# Transition duration not working for bootstraps thumbnail:hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-transitions, thumbnails

I have made the entire thumbnail a link and have specified in the CSS for it to have a transition duration of 0.3s. Unfortunately it does not work. I have tried numerous things, but have not seemed to figured it out.

This is the relevant HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3"> <a href="https://www.cars.com">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="car.jpg" alt="Car">
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the relevant CSS code:

```
.thumbnail{
    transition-duration: 1s;
}

.thumbnail:hover{
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px red;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening / how to fix this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: so, what's your transition animation?

Comment: @TomSarduy the box shadow. A box shadow will be applied to the thumbnail once hovered upon. The hover works and the box shadow appears, but the transition duration has no affect.

Comment: of course not, you need to define the transition property you are trying to animate ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the transition property. You need to specify what css property you are trying to animate. It can be `all` or in this case box-shadow. It should be something like this:

```
.thumbnail{
    transition-duration: 1s;
}

.thumbnail:hover{
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px red;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-property: box-shadow;

}
```

You can check a working example here: 
https://jsbin.com/qosusugige

Good documentation about [CSS transitions in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions).

Comment: I am seriously shocked, it worked. But I have not used this for other hover elements that I am using in my website. Should I be using it? Or only include it when required?

Comment: @Tom: you should always use `transition-property` or the shorten way: `transition: box-shadow 1s`. What could happen is that the transition property is inherited from a parent element. In your case, you are using Bootstrap that comes with some animations and lot of CSS rules by default.

Answer (score 0):

Not only is a transition property missing but somewhere in that bootstrap css stylsheet is preventing transition from being effected use `!important`

```
.thumbnail{
  transition:box-shadow 0.3s !important;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}

.thumbnail:hover{
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px red;
}
```

Snippet below

```css
.thumbnail{
  transition:box-shadow 0.3s !important;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}

.thumbnail:hover{
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3"> <a href="https://www.cars.com">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="car.jpg" alt="Car">
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should not use `all` as the transition property if you only want to animate the `box-shadow`, and it's not performance wise and adding !important is not the right way to solve it.

Comment: and for the `!important`, if that was the case, the best would be to extend the default `.thumbnail` bootstrap class, for example with `.thumbnail--animate` or something like that.